# Parallelize three_for_loop in C++ by openmp

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a code. Here, A, B, C, A1, B1, C1 are vectors in 3 dimensional. A, B, C are independent together and A1, B1, C1 are also independent together. I want to parallelize to calculate it by using openmp. However, I run it with openmp, I get "Segmentation fault" error.Could you help me for this problem? Thank you in advance.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include<math.h> 
#include<cmath> 
#include<vector>    
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{

int NX=801;              // NUmber of grid in X direction
int NY=501;              
int NZ=401;   
float PI=3.14159265358979323846;
unsigned int i,j,k;
vector<vector<vector<float> > > A (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));
vector<vector<vector<float> > > B (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));
vector<vector<vector<float> > > C (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));
vector<vector<vector<float> > > A1 (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));
vector<vector<vector<float> > > B1 (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));
vector<vector<vector<float> > > C1 (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));

cout<<"start"<<endl;
#pragma omp parallel for private (j) shared(A,B,C,i,k,NX,NY,NZ) 
for (i=0;i<NX;i++)
    for (j=0;j<NY;j++)
        for (k=0;k<NZ;k++)
        {
            A[i][j][k]=sin(2.0*PI/float(NX*NY*NZ)*float(i*j*k));
            B[i][j][k]=cos(5.0*PI/float(NX*NY*NZ)*float(i*j*k));
            C[i][j][k]=sin(2.0*PI/float(NX*NY*NZ))*cos(5.0*PI/float(NX*NY*NZ)*float(i*j*k));
        }

#pragma omp parallel for private (j) shared(A1,B1,C1,A,B,C,i,k,NX,NY,NZ) 
for (i=1;i<NX-1;i++)
    for (j=1;j<NY-1;j++)
        for (k=1;k<NZ-1;k++)
        {
            A1[i][j][k]=C[i+1][j][k]*cos(5.0*PI/float(NX*NY*NZ)*float(i*j*k));
            B1[i][j][k]=A[i][j][k]+B[i][j][k]+C[i][j][k]*cos(5.0*PI/float(NX*NY*NZ)*float(i*j*k));
            C1[i][j][k]=16.0*A[i][j][k]*cos(5.0*PI/float(NX*NY*NZ)*float(i*j*k));
        }
cout<<"finish"<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is very easy to parallelise with OpenMP. However, you did some mistakes in your own attempt, notably by trying to declare `i` and `k` `shared` whereas they should actually be `private`. Better even, don't declare the variables in advance and simply declare them inside the `for` loop. This way, they will have automatically the right scope, preventing you from mixing it up.

Here is what it would give:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include<math.h> 
#include<cmath> 
#include<vector>    
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{

    int NX=801;              // NUmber of grid in X direction
    int NY=501;              
    int NZ=401;   
    float PI=3.14159265358979323846;
    vector<vector<vector<float> > > A (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));
    vector<vector<vector<float> > > B (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));
    vector<vector<vector<float> > > C (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));
    vector<vector<vector<float> > > A1 (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));
    vector<vector<vector<float> > > B1 (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));
    vector<vector<vector<float> > > C1 (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));

    cout<<"start"<<endl;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i=0;i<NX;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<NY;j++)
            for (int k=0;k<NZ;k++)
            {
                A[i][j][k]=sin(2.0*PI/float(NX*NY*NZ)*float(i*j*k));
                B[i][j][k]=cos(5.0*PI/float(NX*NY*NZ)*float(i*j*k));
                C[i][j][k]=sin(2.0*PI/float(NX*NY*NZ))*cos(5.0*PI/float(NX*NY*NZ)*float(i*j*k));
            }

    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int i=1;i<NX-1;i++)
        for (int j=1;j<NY-1;j++)
            for (int k=1;k<NZ-1;k++)
            {
                A1[i][j][k]=C[i+1][j][k]*cos(5.0*PI/float(NX*NY*NZ)*float(i*j*k));
                B1[i][j][k]=A[i][j][k]+B[i][j][k]+C[i][j][k]*cos(5.0*PI/float(NX*NY*NZ)*float(i*j*k));
                C1[i][j][k]=16.0*A[i][j][k]*cos(5.0*PI/float(NX*NY*NZ)*float(i*j*k));
            }
    cout<<"finish"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now, since you ask for parallelising this code, I guess you are interested in performance. So nothing should prevent you from implementing one or two very basic performance optimisations like this:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include<math.h> 
#include<cmath> 
#include<vector>    
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{

    int NX=801;              // NUmber of grid in X direction
    int NY=501;              
    int NZ=401;   
    float PI=3.14159265358979323846;
    vector<vector<vector<float> > > A (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));
    vector<vector<vector<float> > > B (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));
    vector<vector<vector<float> > > C (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));
    vector<vector<vector<float> > > A1 (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));
    vector<vector<vector<float> > > B1 (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));
    vector<vector<vector<float> > > C1 (NX,vector<vector<float> >(NY,vector <float>(NZ,0.0)));

    const float PIOverSize = PI/(NX*NY*NZ);
    const float sin2PIOverSize = sin(2.0f*PIOverSize);
    cout<<"start"<<endl;
    double tbeg = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i=0;i<NX;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<NY;j++)
        {
            float IJPIOverSize=i*j*PIOverSize;
            for (int k=0;k<NZ;k++)
            {
                A[i][j][k]=sin(2.0f*IJPIOverSize*k);
                B[i][j][k]=cos(5.0f*IJPIOverSize*k);
                C[i][j][k]=sin2PIOverSize*cos(5.0f*IJPIOverSize*k);
            }
         }
    #pragma omp for 
    for (int i=1;i<NX-1;i++)
        for (int j=1;j<NY-1;j++)
        {
            float IJPIOverSize=i*j*PIOverSize;
            for (int k=1;k<NZ-1;k++)
            {
                A1[i][j][k]=C[i+1][j][k]*cos(5.0f*IJPIOverSize*k);
                B1[i][j][k]=A[i][j][k]+B[i][j][k]+C[i][j][k]*cos(5.0f*IJPIOverSize*k);
                C1[i][j][k]=16.0f*A[i][j][k]*cos(5.0f*IJPIOverSize*k);
            }
        }
    }
    double time = omp_get_wtime() - tbeg;
    cout<<"finish in "<<time<<" seconds"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

With this, your code should already be much faster.

Comment: Now, I total understand your way to parallelize it. It works faster five times compared without parallelization when it is done in my computer. I attempted to make code with as much as possible of calculation, therefore, it was looked very mess. However, the way you optimized is very beautiful. Thank you very much. I learnt a lot from your code.

Comment: Depending on the sizes NX and NY, a "collapse(2)" on your parallel for loops might also help, since it will expose more parallelism.